# Probability of six birthdays in 2 different months

Tags: probability, self-study

What is the probability that the birthdays of 6 different persons will fall in exactly 2 calendar months?
How is the total number of cases $12^6$ and not $6^{12}$?

Comment: It would be nice if you showed some of your workings so it would be possible to correct you where you made a mistake

Comment: One approach is to factor the problem into two steps: count the number of pairs of months and then, for any given pair, compute the chance that all six birthdays will fall in those two months (but not all six in one month).  That reduces the problem to three calculations but each is easy.